# Не работает onYouTubeIframeAPIReady

Tags: javascript, ajax, youtube-api

```
success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
      var split_data = data['text'].replace(/[^0-9]/gim,'')
      if (!data) {
        return null
      }
      var playerNo = next_id-1;
      if (playerNo != 2) {
        player_list.push({
            id: 'player' + playerNo, 
        });
      }
      console.log('player_list: ', player_list)
      var liner_line = products_place.find('.liner-line')
           .append('<div class="box blocks" data-id="'+ next_id +'">' +
                    '<div class="div_to_be_hidden"><span class="news_span"> Новости:'+ ' '  + split_data + '</span></div>' +
                      '<iframe id="player'+next_id+'" width="294" height="165"'+ 
                        'src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/'+ data['data']['video_id'] +'?enablejsapi=1'+'" ' + 
                        'frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen=""> '+
                      '</iframe>' +
                    '</div>'
      )
      var players = new Array()
      window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = function() {
        console.log('> SUCCESS')
        for (var i = 0; i < player_list.length; i++) {
          var curplayer = createPlayer(player_list[i]);
          players[i] = curplayer;
        }  
      }

      function createPlayer(playerInfo) {
        playerInfo.id = new YT.Player(playerInfo.id, {
          events: {
            'onReady': onReady
          }
        });

        function onReady() {
          var player = playerInfo.id
          player.addEventListener('onStateChange', function(e) {
            if(player.getPlayerState() == 3 || player.getPlayerState() == 1) {
              $('.div_to_be_hidden').hide();
              $('.font').hide()
                }
            if(player.getPlayerState() == 0 || player.getPlayerState() == 2) { 
              $('.div_to_be_hidden').show();
              $('.font').show();
            }
          })
        }
      }
    }
```

При успешной загрузке Ajax функция `onYouTubeIframeAPIReady` ни в какую не хочет работать. Есть подозрение, что функция эта вызывается только один раз. Т.к выше в коде у меня точно такой же Ajax запрос, разница в них в том, что первый сразу подгружает два видео при загрузке страницы, а второй, при кликании только грузит видео. В первом случае `onYouTubeIframeAPIReady` - работает, а вот во втором - нет.

Comment: Или,например, как можно функцию эту вынести из двух аякс запросов, сделать общий массив

Answer (score 0):

Была похожая проблема, функция `onYouTubeIframeAPIReady` работала во всех браузерах, кроме Firefox. Заменил `onYouTubeIframeAPIReady` на `onYouTubePlayerAPIReady`, все заработало.